# Eclipse- CVS -Algorithm negotiation failure

Tags: eclipse, cvs

when i try to connect to the CVS server, the following error is shown:

CVS Communication error:         org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ssh2.CVSSSH2ServerConnection$SSH2IOException: algorithm negotiation failure.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest eclipse version fixed the problem for me

Comment: @sina72: given that the OP is answering his own question, I struggle to believe it's not a valid answer.